# Getting array of undefined, promise

Tags: javascript, async-await, promise

From code below I'm getting array of undefined but to be honest I don't know why and how to fix it...

```
const promises = sessionsIds.map((id) =>
            stripe.checkout.sessions
                .listLineItems(id, { limit: 100 })
                .then((err, lineItems) => {
                    return lineItems;
                })
        );

        const usernames = await Promise.all(promises);
```

I have also tried with async await but the result is still the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `stripe.checkout.sessions.listLineItems(id, { limit: 100 })` is returning a regular, standard promise, then the problem is that you're treating is like a regular asynchronous callback with `(err, value)` as the functions arguments.  That's not how `.then()` works.  The first argument to `.then()` is a function that will be called with one argument, the resolved value.  In fact, you probably  don't even need a `.then()` here.

You can change to this:

```
const promises = sessionsIds.map((id) =>
    stripe.checkout.sessions.listLineItems(id, { limit: 100 })
);

const usernames = await Promise.all(promises);
```

Or, simplifying further:

```
const usernames = await Promise.all(sessionsIds.map((id) =>
    stripe.checkout.sessions.listLineItems(id, { limit: 100 })
));
```

Note, the `.then()` handler here is not necessary (assuming `stripe.checkout.sessions.listLineItems(id, { limit: 100 })` already returns a promise).  If you want to use a `.then()` handler, it would go like this:

```
const promises = sessionsIds.map((id) =>
    stripe.checkout.sessions.listLineItems(id, { limit: 100 })
      .then((lineItems) => {
           console.log(lineItems);
           return lineItems;
      });
);

const usernames = await Promise.all(promises);
```

Where you pass it a function as the first argument and it gets one argument (the resolved value).

Comment: Ohh you are right! I was really overthinking how it works :facepalm:
Thank you so much for the answer!